# where is the Android Studio executable

Tags: android-studio, installation

Where is the Android Studio executable file stored in the system?

I have it installed, but have unpinned it from the taskbar, which was the only shortcut I had. Since I can't find it in File Explorer, I can't load it.

I've tried the Start menu search function, and used File Explorer to search the entire install directory. The only thing left I can think of to do is reinstall it, but I don't really want to do that, as it was working fine.

P.S. I wasn't sure if this was more appropriate for SuperUser, since it's not directly coding related, or SO, since I doubt the number of people on SuperUser with the answer.

Comment: Don't send the whole paragraph of problem you are having. Be specific for what you are asking

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro, thanks

Comment: Default location is C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe
If on a 64 bit machine run studio64.exe instead

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find the executable file in bin folder where the android studio is installed, default location is

**Windows**

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe

There is also `studio64.exe` in the same directory for 64-bit machines

**Linux**

> path_to\android-studio\bin\studio.sh

Comment: Hmm, I found studio.exe in a subfolder of my downloads folder...that's definitely not where I told it to install, though I did extract the .zip there...well, whatever happened, I think that's what I was looking for, so thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu/Gnome make sure you create an application file in

```
/usr/share/applications/android-studio.desktop
```

with the following content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=AndroidStudio
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Terminal=false
Icon=/path/to/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Comment=Android Studio
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=AndroidStudio
```

This way you will be able to find Android Studio in the applications list, create desktop shortcuts for Android Studio or add it to the favourites bar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember how did I installed Android Studio on my Ubuntu 16.04, but my  android studio executable is located as `/snap/bin/android-studio`.

Comment: Well, the answer is right in your face, you used [a snap package](https://snapcraft.io/about) since your executable ended up in `/snap` ;) I hope I have refreshed your memory.